# Android modify Font type, font size, font color of text in ArrayAdapter in Gridview

Tags: android, fonts, android-arrayadapter, font-size, android-gridview

Is it possible modify Font type, font size, font color of text in Gridview (Android API level 8 and above) ? How?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GridView gridView;

    static final String[] numbers = new String[] { 
                "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setActivityBackgroundColor();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter); 


}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="55dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"    
    >

</GridView>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes it's possible for this u will need to create a custom ArrayAdapter for gridView

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Thanks, i would try for same, also http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/ custom adapter can be used

Comment: if u have still issue then share your code what u have tried